# Docker container cant run pygame

Tags: python, docker, pygame

so actually, i want to run a pygame application using docker container. however, when i run the docker and click the link at the terminal, it opens a tab and it says : "The webpage at http://0.0.0.0:8000/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address."

here's the aliens.py github link: https://github.com/xamox/pygame/blob/master/examples/aliens.py

in the aliens.py file, I added some code into it:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()
```

and

```
if __name__ == '__main__': uvicorn.run(app, port=8000, host="0.0.0.0")
```

and for the code of the Dockerfile file that I have created:

```
Python FROM:3.10

WORKDIR /fastapi-app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./app ./app

CMD["python", "./app/aliens.py"]
```

Is the problem is in the IP address of the host?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to use 0.0.0.0 ("listen to all interfaces") as an IP address in a URL.  You probably need to connect to `http://localhost:12345`, where the port number 12345 matches the first half of your `docker run -p 12345:8000` option and the second half matches the `port=` option in your service.  How are you launching the container?

Comment: so in the terminal, i install the venv with "python -m venv venv", then i activate it. then i install the uvicorn, fastapi, and the pygame, after that i freeze the requirements.txt, and then i build the docker with "docker build -t python-fastapi ."  and then run it with "docker run -p 8000:8000 python-fastapi"

Comment: Everything happens in the container build, with the docker run command you provided, the uvicorn server will be accesible from http://localhost:8000.

Comment: what distribution do you run in docker? PyGame may need distribution which runs XWindows and have access to Video Card. It will NOT run if system runs only in text mode.

Answer (score 0):

**Dockerfile**

```
# python FROM:3.10    <----
FROM python:3.10 

WORKDIR /fastapi-app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./app ./app

#CMD["python", "./app/aliens.py"]
#   ^ whitespace missing
CMD ["python", "./app/aliens.py"]
```

**aliens.py**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn
app = FastAPI()


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    uvicorn.run(app, port=8000, host="0.0.0.0")
```

**Testing without aliens-code**

```
# build
$ docker build -t my-app .
# run
$ docker run -d -rm --name mayapp -p 80:8000 my-app
# 80 host-port
# 8000 container-port
$ docker ps -a 
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED         
STATUS        PORTS                  NAMES
5ba7b461e92e   my-app    "python ./app/aliens…"   3 seconds ago   Up 1 second   0.0.0.0:80->8000/tcp   mayapp
```

http://localhost/docs
[image]